# Find policy numbers

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `tblEnrollmentMaster` and `tblEnrollmentMaster_07232019`.
I want to fetch such policy_numbers which have different `effective_date` and `pt_date` in both the tables.

The fields in both the tables are:

```
Column_name:

EnrollmentID
FamilyID
TPA_CODE
PROCESS_DATE
POLICY_NUMBER
MEMBER_NUMBER
DEPENDENT_NUMBER
DEPENDENT_TYPE
MEMBERSHIP_MOVEMENT_LISTING
CLIENT_NUMBER
APPLICATION_NUMBER
EFFECTIVE_DATE1
EPP_SCHEME_ISSUE_DATE
PRODUCT_CODE
Sub_Prod_Code
TYPE_OF_CHANGE
DATE_OF_BIRTH1
AGE
SEX
SALUTATION
SURNAME
GIVEN_NAME
DTEATT
DESCRIPTION
HEIGHT
WEIGHT
MOBILE_PHONE
TELEPHONE_NO_1
TELEPHONE_NO_2
INTERNET_ADDRESS
CLIENT_ADDR_1
CLIENT_ADDR_2
CLIENT_ADDR_3
CLIENT_ADDR_4
CLIENT_ADDR_5
CLIENT_PCODE
TOTAL_PREMIUM
NO_CLAIM_BONUS_AMOUNT
PAID_TO_DATE1
INCLUSION_1
INCLUSION_2
INCLUSION_3
INCLUSION_4
INCLUSION_5
EXCLUSION_1
EXCLUSION_2
EXCLUSION_3
EXCLUSION_4
EXCLUSION_5
NO_OF_YEARS_1
NO_OF_YEARS_2
NO_OF_YEARS_3
NO_OF_YEARS_4
NO_OF_YEARS_5
POLICY_OWNER_NAME
ADDRESS_LINES_1
ADDRESS_LINES_2
ADDRESS_LINES_3
ADDRESS_LINES_4
ADDRESS_LINES_5
ADDRESS_LINES_6
BENEFICIARY_NAME
APPOINTEE_1_FOR_MINOR
CLIENT_DATE_OF_BIRTH
RELATIONSHIP_TO_LIFE_INSURE
ORIGINAL_COMMENCEMENT_DATE1
PREMIUM_FREQUENCY
SUM_INSURED
COVER_DHCB_INDICATOR
COVER_CI_INDICATOR
COVER_SB_INDICATOR
INCOME_BENEFIT_INDICATOR
OCCUPATION
BENEFICIARY_SALUTATION
ADDRESS_1
ADDRESS_2
ADDRESS_3
ADDRESS_4
ADDRESS_5
ADDRESS_6
LAPSED_DATE
REINSTATEMENT_DATE
EFFECTIVE_DATE
DATE_OF_BIRTH
PAID_TO_DATE
ORIGINAL_COMMENCEMENT_DATE
STATUS_CODE
ISSUE_DATE
CHANGE_TYPE
SUB_TYPE
TEXT
ATT_DATE
PEMXTPRM
POAXTPRM
BENEFICIARY_RELATION
TRANSACTION_TYPE
RECORD_IDENTITY
MLVL_PLAN
EMP_NO
ANNUALIZED_PREMIUM
MODAL_PREMIUM
PTDATE
ZINCLU01
ZINCLU02
ZINCLU03
ZINCLU04
ZINCLU05
ZEXCLU01
ZEXCLU02
ZEXCLU03
ZEXCLU04
ZEXCLU05
EFDATE
APPMINONE
ADDRLINE_1
ADDRLINE_2
ADDRLINE_3
ADDRLINE_4
ADDRLINE_5
ADDRLINE_6
POLICY_OWNER_NUMBER
MEMBER_DATE_OF_BIRTH
RISK_COMMENCEMENT_DATE
POLICY_INFO_DATE
POLICY_TYPE
SUMINSURED
SubProdID
ClaimLodgedAmt
UpdateDate
IsActive
Inserteddate
FileName
BATCHID
CHDRCOY
SECUITYNO
SUBTYPE
DTETRM
TPAUHID
PPREM
ZOWNSALUT
ADDRSS01
ADDRSS02
ADDRSS03
ADDRSS04
ADDRSS05
ADDRSS06
ZAPPSALUT
DTEEFF
ZTRNTYP
ZPRTSMIN
ZBLSMINS
ZMATBEN
ZPRVNM01
ZPRVNM02
ZPRVNM03
ZPRVNM04
ZPRVNM05
ZPREVPOL01
ZPREVPOL02
ZPREVPOL03
ZPREVPOL04
ZPREVPOL05
ZRRBNF
ZREBNF
ZRSTBAMT
DESCITEM
LONGDESC
SHORTDESC
POLICY_IN_FORCE_DATE
testing_Flag
HDFC_Flag
Phs_id
```

Please help me find such policy_numbers whose `effective_date` and `pt_date` are different in both the tables.

Comment: What column is linking the tables?

Comment: all the columns are same in both the tables

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `EnrollmentID` is the `PRIMARY KEY`

```
SELECT a.POLICY_NUMBER 
FROM   tblEnrollmentMaster as a
INNER JOIN tblEnrollmentMaster_07232019 as b
ON     a.EnrollmentID = b.EnrollmentID
WHERE  a.effective_date <> b.effective_date AND a.pt_date <> b.pt_date
```

Comment: enrollmentid is different in both the tables hence we cannot join on enrollment id

Comment: also we have duplicate effective and pt_date in the table enrollment master against a single policy_number and both of the records are having isactive=0